# High frequency RF coupler manufacturing tips

Tags: rf, manufacturing

I am trying to manufacture a component at 35GHz. Its Rogers 6202 5mil width.

0.274 is 50ohms.

In the simulation its all good and ideal, but in real life there could be problems.

If you could, please give me advice regarding the following points:

1. How do I choose a proper connector for 35GHz?
2. Tips for a proper transition from connector to the trace.
3. Things in manufacturing that could ruin the performance and how what counter measures to take. (Etch factor, non-uniform dielectric constant, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at 36GHz, you're going to need either 2.92 or 2.4mm connectors. (Reference from here https://www.amphenolrf.com/frequency-range-chart ) How you connect your traces to the connectors will take some more detailed modeling to get the transition from the connector to the trace optimized with low reflections. You're going to need to include the ground plane as well, as that is part of the model.

Next you're going to need to figure out how you're going to mechanically support the RF connectors so that they don't rip off the board when you make cabled connections to them. For example here is a link to a Pasternak RF directional coupler (https://www.pasternack.com/directional-10-db-2.92mm-coupler-40-ghz-pe2cp1133-10-p.aspx) which is an example of what a commercial coupler looks like.